# how to clear the text field after alert is generated and we press "OK"

Tags: iphone, ios, uialertview

I have a login screen and when userid or password is incorrect, an alert is generated. Now when the user presses "OK" it returns back to login screen but doesn't clear the text field and still has the previous input.

How to remove it?

my code for alert msg is:

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                                                      message:@"Login id or password is incorrect"
                                                     delegate:nil
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

    [message show];
```

Thanks.

Comment: Use the alertview delegate methods - - (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex..... if(buttonIndex == 0) then ok is pressed... and clear the textfield then....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set `delegate` to `self`

Your alert will be :

```
    UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"      message:@"Login id or password is incorrect" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [message show];
```

and use :

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==0)
     {
         [yourTextField setText:@""];
     }
}
```

Comment: @iNoob +1 for a quick answer :)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //cancel clicked ...do your action
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

add `UIAlertViewDelegate` in  .h file and add this into .m file

```
UIAlertView *message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login Failed"
                                                      message:@"Login id or password is incorrect"
                                                     delegate:self
                                            cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                            otherButtonTitles:nil];

[message show];


- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    if(buttonIndex==alertView.cancelButtonIndex)
     {
         [yourTextField setText:@""];
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry forgot to change that. :)

Comment: @HChouhan02: Is your answer different than iNoob?

Comment: not at all but i use `if(buttonIndex==alertView.cancelButtonIndex)` and iNoob used `if(buttonIndex==0)`

Comment: @HChouhan02: Ok but that you could have done just by editing iNoob's answer. Rather than posting it as separate answer. Nothing Personal :)

Comment: no dear i not copied iNood answer i just copied user1253637 code so that by mistake i just forget to change that nil to self.

Answer (score 0):

try this one in your login screen go to viewWillDisappear and make you textfield to nil,  it may solve your problem